# How to query data from Firebase and place it in a textField, to be modified and update the databse entry

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'll explain myself better with some examples now.

Basically I have a working login and registration process and whenever one user registers, he gets added to the DB on Firebase. Now, when he registers I get:

- Name
- Surname
- email

and they all are added to the user information.

My Database has this structure:

[image: DB Structure]

Now, my task is to get the "nome" value (name in italian...) to print out [image: here]
, but how in the hell do I do this? The placeholder has to be substituted with the data from the DB and if the user changes it and presses the button it should modify the entry in the DB.

I read all the documentation and feel very stupid having not yet solved this problem.

Please help me!

This is all the code I have right now:

```
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    var userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        userID = String(userID!)
    
    let utenti = db.collection("utenti").document()
    let nomeUtente = utenti.getDocument("nome")
```

Code of the button I use to register my users to the DB:

```
{
    
    // Verifico nome e cognome
    
    let erroreNome_Cognome = validazioneCampi()
    
    if erroreNome_Cognome != nil {
        // In caso non fossero compilati i campi do errore.
        mostraErrore(erroreNome_Cognome!)
    } else if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {   // Uso binding opzionale per evitare errori con i valori
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
                if let e = error { // Uso di nuovo optional binding per errore
                    self.labelErrore.text = e.localizedDescription
                } else {
                    // Pulisco i dati per il DB - Uso .trimmingCharacters per rimuovere, usando whitespacesAndNewlines, spazi e punti a capo
                    let nome = self.nomeTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let cognome = self.cognomeTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    
                    // Quello che ho appena fatto, è possibile anche per la verifica dei dati svolta prima con erroreNome_Cognome. Infatti, senza di esso non potrei spacchettare il
                    // dato con "!".
                    
                    // Qui creo l'utente nel database
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    
                    db.collection("utenti").addDocument(data: ["nome":nome, "cognome":cognome, "email": email, "uid": authResult!.user.uid]) { (erroreNome_Cognome) in
                        
                        if erroreNome_Cognome != nil {
                            // Mostra errore
                            self.mostraErrore("I dati utenti non sono validi per il database")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Naviga alla pagina successiva qui
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registratiAWelcome", sender:self)
                }
            }
        }
    


}
```

Comment: You have to edit your questions and show some code, working or not. Do you know how to fetch from Firestore? do you know how to make the UI? Do you know architecture? concentrate in one problema at a time. To me this doesn't sound like a question. Instead sounds like you want the full answer to all or a tutorial, there are many tutorials on the web

Comment: Hi @JavierVieira, no I don't want a full tutorial and yes, there are many online. I watched them and didn't understand how to do this fetching. That is why I'm asking here. I don't know how to fetch an exact information like "nome" in this case and cannot find a good solution, so I asked here. I have not code right now and I'm going mad with the Firebase documentation...

Comment: Please don't use links in questions, if the link breaks it will make the question useless to future readers. That one is not working for me for example so I have no idea what your structure looks like. Please embed Firestore structures *in the question* so it will be visible to all.  Performing this task is pretty well covered in the Firestore Getting Started Guide [Read Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: @Jay I'll change it now :)

Comment: Much better! You have a bunch of options. The first one  would be to write a query to retrieve the user you want. That's covered in the documentation [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). The second and probably better option is to store users using their UID as the documentId. Then you can read the document directly with their UID. That's also covered in the docs [Get a Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: Hi @Jay, I just added the code I use to register the users to my DB, do you think this is good? Should I change something?

Comment: At first glance, it looks ok. However, how your data is structures is dependent on how you're going to query your data. For example, `addDocument` allows Firestore to create the documentId e.g. a Cloud Firestore auto-generated ID. So as I mentioned above, your going to have to query for that user whenever you want to retreive it. If you create the document with the users uid, it can be accessed directly without a query `db.collection("users").document(uid).setData(usersData)`

Comment: `db.collection("utenti").addDocument(data: ["nome":nome, "cognome":cognome, "email": email, "uid": authResult!.user.uid]) { (erroreNome_Cognome) in`

So this should become this:

`db.collection("utenti").document(udid).setData(["nome":nome, "cognome":cognome, "email": email, "uid": authResult!.user.uid]) { (erroreNome_Cognome) in` ?

Comment: yes and I sencond what @jay says, when I store a profile of the user, I use the uid of the user as the document id. That way is a lot easer to query you just query as the second part of my answer
`let docRef = db.collection("utenti").document(uid)`

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari It's generally Best Practice to post longer segments of code in questions because they are crazy hard to read in comments. But, what you posted looks to be correct. Also, you probably don't need to also store the uid in the document because it's the documentId and can be read any time you read the document `doc.documentId` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I can see that you already have your Firebase into your project.

Let's review your code:

When you are doing:

```
db.collection("utenti").document()
```

you are telling Firestore that you want to create a new document, and to create a reference to the future document. So nothing to do with this, if you want more information about this method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

then when you are doing

```
utenti.getDocument("nome")
```

nome is a field of your document, it's not a document, and this document "nome" doesn't exists. If you want to query a specific document, you should do for example:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let docRef = db.collection("utenti").document("cwmG6g0xgVe6txYSfKqm")
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

More info about this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Now with the current structure that you have on your database, what you would like to do base on you user uid is a query to all the documents, then this documents will have the fields like "nome"

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
db.collection("utenti").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userID).getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
    if let error = error {
       print(error)
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
}
```

you have more information https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Hope this helps, I know you will have more questions, but play debugging the information and trying around to get a grip of Firestore SDK

Comment: Super good answer. I would like to add that it's common practice to store users within Firestore with the users UID as the documentId. By doing that, you can directly access the users node in a light-weight way instead of much heavier query.

Comment: Hi, this work really fine and I get a good print of all the documents inside of it, I'll try selecting the exact documents and send them to my TextFields. Thanks!